# Difficulties deploying React + Spring Boot application to Heroku, Frontend does not render

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku, webpack, deployment

I am attempting to get my Spring Boot and React Frontend application deployed and hosted on Heroku. When I added a test mapping to the "/" endpoint on the Spring Boot side of the code I confirmed that the backend portion of my app seemed to be working fine as the website the content of that route. However, removing the test mapping and attempting to have the base address render my Frontend has proven difficult as nothing displays...

But within heroku logs I can see the app is attempting to process the visit to the root address "/"

**Heroku Logs**

```
2023-05-23T00:51:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-05-23T00:51:23.855296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=recipiece.herokuapp.com request_id=755f602e-05c2-40ad-a471-a1d20fa485a5 fwd="74.15.109.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=61ms status=404 bytes=522 protocol=https
2023-05-23T00:51:23.812972+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-05-23T00:51:23.812Z  INFO 2 --- [io-35494-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-23T00:51:23.813114+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-05-23T00:51:23.813Z  INFO 2 --- [io-35494-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-23T00:51:23.813854+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-05-23T00:51:23.813Z  INFO 2 --- [io-35494-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

From my understanding I would create a webpack.config.js to tell Heroku where the entry point is for this React app. Through other posts and resources I've determined that firstly I must specify the entry point of my frontend to Heroku. Which I attempted to do through a webpack.config file:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/src/App.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
};
```

However, I would need to make sure the application installs all required dependencies and builds the frontend app. So I also have a heroku-postbuild script as follows:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install npm && run build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

But these don't seem to be enough. So from what I've gathered I could potentially solve the issue via a Maven plugin to tell the backend where to fetch the built version of my frontend.

**Maven-Resources-Plugin Solution?**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/resources</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>/path/to/react/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But if my package.json postbuild script isn't working then the directory I point the plugin to will not exist. So I am unsure where exactly I've made my error but any insight, guidance or resources would be greatly appreciated. My leading assumption being I would need to create a Procfile which would allow me to start the server and frontend together on app start. Apologies in advance this is my first attempt at a Spring + React application. If it assists at all my project structure is as follows:

[image]